# Is there a JS library that would grant vim key bindings to a textarea?

Tags: library, javascript, text-editor, keyboard-shortcuts

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/527895/edit-text-areas-using-vi-key-bindings-inside-the-textbox-in-firefox-without-o) is a related question, but I am wondering if there is a pure JS solution that a server could serve so that all client browsers can enjoy the vim keybindings without extra client-side extensions.